Chrome's print page is grayed out and stuck for all webpages, but works perfectly for PDF files
Every attempt to print webpages in the latest PortableApps Chrome (currently v125.0.6422.61) in Windows 10 is just grayed out and fails with a message of Print preview failed. Note nothing is clickable there except the Cancel button. It happens without extensions, both in regular and Incognito mode, and in multiple profiles.
But if I open PDF files in Chrome, the print screen works as usual. So basically I can print PDF files in Chrome but nothing else.
Is there any idea how to fix this?


Turns out it's an official bug as reported in https://issues.chromium.org/issues/339994760 and encountered by various users.
Will update here if it's solved.

It is permission issue.
Go to Chrome folder and right click, select properties-->security tab-->Edit and add "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES" with permisions: Read &execute, List folder contents, Read. Check names so as to be sure and you are ready.
Or execute this command on cmd as admin:
icacls "pathToInstalationFolderOfChrome" /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES":(OI)(CI)(RX)
Replace pathToInstalationFolderOfChrome with chrome's installation path, example "C:\Software\Chrome".

No extra permissions were needed in previous versions. Let's hope they fix it natively.
